# regex to remove all but sha256 notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document with a lot of spread out SHA256 in it.

I want to keep only the SHA256 (let's say there are 500 sha256 in it) and remove all the other text.

For example:

```
asdasd  59A412341527D3F10BCBAD26536428772144767D5325710B245367505B0D8024  obe\read
Lsdfsdf 21A410631527D3F10BCBAD26536428772144767D5325710B2F9D668057864444    c:\pr0
```

TO

```
21A410631527D3F10BCBAD26536428772144767D5325710B2F9D668057864444
59A412341527D3F10BCBAD26536428772144767D5325710B245367505B0D8024
```

I have part of it, but I cant manage to keep only the sha's, what I currently have is the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]{64}` which finds all string that have 64 letters.

Maybe we can even remove the lower case `a-z` since sha is almost never using lower case letters.

thank you, I tried methods that I saw in the forums but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Use [`(\b[A-Z\d]{64}\b)|(?:(?!\b[A-Z\d]{64}\b).)*`](https://regex101.com/r/dY7wO9/1) and replace with `$1`, better?

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(\b[A-Z\d]{64}\b)|(?:(?!\b[A-Z\d]{64}\b).)*
```

and replace with `$1`.

**Details**:

- `(\b[A-Z\d]{64}\b)` - Capture group 1  matching 64 symbols, uppercase letters or digits, as whole words due to the fact that there are word boundaries around the subpattern
- `|` - or
- `(?:(?!\b[A-Z\d]{64}\b).)*` - any other text up to the first occurrence of the first subpattern.